# Delete specific path from history react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have route `/devices` where I have `device1` and `device2` . Clicking on `device1` sends me to `/devices/device1` ( `history.push('/device1')` ), same with `device2` . I have a logo that sends me to `/devices` (history.push).

If I go to `device1` > `logo` > `device2` > `logo` > `device1` > `logo` > `device2` and i delete `device2` and do `history.replace('/devices')`, than on back button i can not go to url `/devices/device2` because I have replaced it, but if I go couple more back button clicks I am on the `/devices/device2` url because it is still in history.

How can I remove completely `/devices/device2` from the history? I hope someone understands the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for us to programmatically reset the history stack (at least in a browser, in-memory history this would be trivial). If you need to clear the history stack for some reason, I'd suggest you use window.location.reload().

Response from react-router creators:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/567#issuecomment-386323573